# Optimizar codigo para eliminar valor de array

Tags: php

Tengo este codigo:

```
//empezamos con articulos
    $ConsArticulos = Consulta_Dinamica("Array","id,color","Articulos","(FIND_IN_SET ('".$_SESSION["Empresa_Id"]."', `empresa`)) AND (FIND_IN_SET ('".$_POST["ReasViejoColor"]."', `color`))");
    foreach($ConsArticulos as $Darticulos) { 
    $Articulosviej = explode(',',$Darticulos["color"]);
for ($i=0;$i<count($Articulosviej);$i++) { if ($Articulosviej[$i] == $_POST["ReasViejoColor"]) { $Articulosviej[$i] = $_POST["ReasNuevoColor"]; } }
    $Articulosviej = implode(",", $Articulosviej);
    $UpArtiColor = Actualizar_Datos("Articulos" , "`color` = '".$Articulosviej."' " ,"id","".$Darticulos["id"]."");
} //fin de articulos
```

Lo que hace es eliminar un valor de un array y sustituirlo por otro. Funcionar funciona pero tengo sensación de que es un código muy sucio y que debe existir alguna función que haga esto mismo directamente.

El valor a sustituir del array viene de un campo de mysql que esta separado por `,`

el array que me saca la primera consulta es este:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 165
            [color] => 301,304,303,300
        )

)
```

en este caso solo tiene un valor, pero lo normal es que tenga varios, en algunos casos color solo tiene un valor, pero en su mayoría tiene varios.

La cosa seria leer ese array y sustituir uno de los valores por uno nuevo, como hago en el for de mi código.

Había probado con un array_remplace pero no he sido capaz de ponerlo en marcha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No necesitas el bucle `for`. `str_replace` puede trabajar perfectamente con arrays:

```
$Articulosviej = explode(',', $Darticulos["color"]);
$Articulosviej = str_replace($_POST["ReasViejoColor"], $_POST["ReasNuevoColor"], $Articulosviej);
$Articulosviej = implode(',', $Articulosviej);
```

[Fiddle](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/449909e40b17990663d20d86aeb96736c259263b)